# How would I go about converting layered planes into one consistent model?

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, scripting, modifiers

I'm trying to create 3D closed and singular meshes using collections of 2D planes showing the outline of the shape at that coordinate. I.e. I'm trying to make a cake and I have the separate layers. I just need them to be joined in an automated manner (as there are multiple of these and they can be quite detailed).

Previously I was doing this by creating a convex hull around the layers which I then remeshed to add vertices, once that was done I shrinkwrapped the hull with the original layers as the target and that seemed to get me good results. This doesn't work for this specific instance as the dimensions are quite different leading to vertices being shrinkwrapped to the wrong areas.

I also attempted to use the solidify modifier which does give me close to the desired result however the result isn't usable for me as it doesn't seem to work well with remesh modifier (hardly recognisable result) which is problematic since the final model needs to be smoothed (also problematic immediately after solidifying).

Is there any way to create the hull from the points without it being convex?

I am first and foremost a programmer so coded solutions are viable.

[image: top down view of the problem planes]

[image: image of layered planes]

Comment: I would look into raycasting. By casting a ray through a point and checking or collisions, you can figure out what part of the scene has the planes in it, and generate a model from that.

Comment: Do all the layers have the same amount of vertices?

Comment: @lemon No as far as I'm aware they don't. But I think they are approximately (if not exactly) the same distance apart.

Comment: @person132 I hadn't thought about it in a purely raycasting way so I will try see if I can think of something using raycasts. My approach using the convex hull => shrinkwrap was essentially my attempt at raycasting by using the hulls vertices to all raycast inwards.